# awk or perl one-liner to print line if second field is longer than 7 chars

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file of 1000 lines, each line has 2 words, separated by a space.  How can I print each line only if the last word length is greater than 7 chars?  Can I use awk RLENGTH?  is there an easy way in perl?

Answer (score 10):

@OP, awk's RLENGTH is used when you call `match()` function. Instead, use the `length()` function to check for length of characters

```
awk 'length($2)>7' file
```

if you are using bash, a shell solution

```
while read -r a b
do
  if [ "${#b}" -gt 7 ];then
    echo $a $b
  fi
done <"file"
```

Comment: +1 awk rocks. Note that it automatically prints all matching lines so you dont have to mess with any printf calls!

Answer (score 9):

```
perl -ane 'print if length($F[1]) > 7'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
perl -ne '@a=split/\s+/; print if length($a[1]) > 7' input_file.txt
```

Options used:

```
    -n  assume 'while () { ... }' loop around program
    -e  'command'    one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

You can use the auto-split option as used by Chris

```
    -a  autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane 'length $F[1] > 7 && print' <input_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print if (length($F[$#F]) > 7)' fileName
```

or

```
perl -pae '$_ = "" if (length($F[$#F]) <= 7)' fileName
```